# passing C++11 lambda by templated reference

Tags: c++, lambda, c++11

In gcc 4.5, the following code compiles and works as expected with `-std=c++0x`,

```
#include <stdio.h>

template<typename H>
void caller(H h)
{
    h();
}

int main()
{
    auto c = [](){ printf("A\n"); };
    caller(c);
    caller([](){ printf("B\n"); });
    return 0;
}
```

Prints,

```
A
B
```

However, if `caller` is defined to take a reference,

```
template<typename H>
void caller(H &h)
{
    h();
}
```

The compiler complains,

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:61:34: error: no matching function for call to ‘caller(main()::<lambda()>)’
test.cpp:52:6: note: candidate is: void caller(H&) [with H = main()::<lambda()>]
```

Why?

This seems to break the idea of lambdas providing value semantics for functions, but moreover it means I can't write certain small functions inline which is a bit annoying.

(Is this fixed in newer versions of gcc?  I haven't had a chance to test.)

Edit:  I just discovered the following actually works:

```
template<typename H>
void caller(H *h)
{
    (*h)();
}

int main()
{
    auto c = [](){ printf("A\n"); };
    caller(&c);
    caller(&([](){ printf("B\n"); }));
}
```

I didn't think I'd be able to take the address of a temporary like that.  Maybe that sort of solves the problem, though annoying to require users of the function to pass in the address of the closure instead of a convenient reference.

Comment: @Vlad: Oh hey, that `&&` operator worked.  What does that mean in this context?  Not "and" I guess.  I've never seen `&&` used that way.

Comment: @Steve `&&` is an rvalue reference.

Comment: Huh.  Learning new things.  Thanks!

Comment: Your second example using a pointer is a bug. GCC 4.7.1 [fails](http://liveworkspace.org/code/722aa0f94fd241c9e72d8891caca9b9d) to compile it. Edit: VS2010 allows it too but if you turn up the warnings to level 4 you get this from: *warning C4238: nonstandard extension used : class rvalue used as lvalue*

Comment: At the end of your question, you said you were able to take the address of the temporary lambda. Can you tell us more. g++ will allow this with the `-f permissive` warning - is this what you did?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're trying to pass a temporary by non-const reference.  That won't work for any type.

Pass the lambda by const reference instead.

Comment: Thanks.  Aren't lambdas `const` by default?  Or at least, immutable.

Comment: @Steve by default, yes, but they can be `mutable`.

Comment: Yes, they are immutable by default.  But that still means that you must explicitly use `const H&`.  I'm curious though about the pointer solution though - in that case is `H` equal to `const TheLambdaType` in order that `H*` be `const TheLambdaType *`?

Comment: @AaronMcDaid as Prætorian says, taking the address of a temporary is illegal.